# Merging a common project with build variations in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a .net mvc site that should be published to a lot of different customers, and thus vary slightly depending on the target.

Is there any way to set up the core project structure, e.g. (simplified):

- views
- models
- controllers
- assets
- bin

and make a merge at build time with whatever variations the current target might have. For example:

**core project:**

- views

  - view1.cshtml
  - view2.cshtml

(removed rest of the folders for brevity)

**customer 1 target:**

- views

  - view2.cshtml
  - view3.cshtml

**desired merge result:**

- views

  - view1.cshtml (from core project)
  - view2.cshtml (from customer 1 target)
  - view3.cshtml (from customer 1 target)

The same rule should apply to controllers, binaries etc.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: Maintaining different versions of the application for each customer sounds like it's going to lead to a pretty wide variety of problems.  Why not have a single version of the application and enable/disable features based on settings?

Comment: @David That would work to an extent, but what if a customer wants a couple of views related to him only? I would prefer to keep those views in a project related to that customer only, and only deliver them when I target that specific customer, rather than using a feature toggle.

Comment: If you really want to do something like this, you should make the customer specific features as plugins to the core system. My two cents.

Comment: Upvote for practical question :)

Comment: you need a custom razor view engine to combine your views as your requirement, and implement custom script and css bundling class, try to make a modular architecture so you can compile your project and load customers codes on runtime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would either use multiple projects, nuget, or use source control.  I will talk about these ideas below, but in no particular order.  By the end I may include a preference towards one or the other.

First idea I'll talk about is to use multiple projects.  Create your base project, let's call it WebBase.  Create your core website that you have talked about.  Next create Customer1 website, if you create Customer1 as an empty website you will need to recreate the folder structures in WebBase or you cane create it the same as you did with WebBase and remove all the files(do this from within Visual Studio); either way you end up with the folder structure with no files. I would recommend keeping web.config,packages.config, Properties folder with AssemblyInfo.cs.  Then you will add the files from WebBase, but don't just add them normally.  For illustration's purpose let's do the Home Index View:  Expand the Views Folder in Customer1, Right click on home, choose add, choose Exising Item, browse out of Customer1 and then in to WebBase/Views/Home and single click index.cshtml, now notice the drop down on the button?  click that and choose "Add as Link".  Now do this for all the files in WebBase!  It will seem cumbersome to choose "add as link" every time, but if you just click add, it will copy the file and updates won't propagate from WebBase to Customer1!  Also, you will see things like remove from project vs delete (with prompt about permanent deletion).

Second thought would be to create a nuget package for WebBase and you can than install it as a package, the benefit of this approach would be versioning and it would not require you to update every project with each little change.  It would keep each project completely isolated.  Down side is you would need to update each project individually to propagate changes globally.  You would need to learn about nuget's nuspec file and how to include files and such.  It isn't that bad, it is just XML.  But you can indicate which files to include when the package is installed/updated.

Third would be source control, I know with git you can use submodule to include a seperate project (even from external repository).  Which might be an option, or you could just create a WebBase branch, setup WebBase and then branch it off into each Customer's website.  So create a branch called Customer1, start adding the custom customer things.  Switch back to WebBase, create a new branch called  Customer2... you are off to the races.  Switch back to WebBase, make a global change and then merge these changes into Customer1 and Customer2 branches.

Okay, I will admit it, I would probably go with the third option.  It gives you lots of benefit with little downside.  It even get gives you history!  If you aren't currently using source control... you should!  You can install git on your machine and have the ability to check code in locally and you don't have to worry about an external repository (although I would recommend you have one as it gives you DR).

Either way, there are options available.  But nothing like a single project with configurable file includes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Your requirement is a great candidate for a custom Visual Studio Project Template.

I am thinking of preparing one big project with all the features you're deploying to whatever customer. This project also could be the *trunk* that you might update when a new feature or a fix is needed. Then, [export the trunk-solution into a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates). Then continue with [VSIX project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-the-vsix-project-template) and [incorporate a wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) into it, to collect user input on a project creation. Based on the input take the appropriate action and add/remove the necessary files or enable/disable features as needed.

Or you might just keep the source files on the file system and organize them into the template on the fly - i.e., as a result of the user input during the wizard. At the end of the wizard, the template is deployed and ... voila.

Answer (score 5):

First thing that comes in mind (and probably easiest because it does not require any additional tooling) is to create core project with core functionality, views and controllers. And for each customer create separate project with custom views and controllers. Then for customer-specific project simply link all required files from core project. It can be a little tedious to link the files depending on the number, but seems doable.

Another approach could be to use tools like [CAKE](https://cakebuild.net/) or [FAKE](https://fake.build/), with the help of which you can script the entire build process the way you want, but I never tried doing such custom scripting myself.

Third option that I can work as well is to conditionally include files based on defined constant, but that will require editing *.csproj files. The code can be something like:

```
<Content Include="Views\View1.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Views\View2.cshtml" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('CORE'))" />
<Content Include="Views\View2.cshtml" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('CUSTOMER1'))" />
<Content Include="Views\View3.cshtml" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('CORE'))" />
<Content Include="Views\View3.cshtml" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('CUSTOMER1'))" />
```

Not sure how easy it will be to maintain it though.

I would probably consider to split the application into independent components/projects that will contain all functionality related to the component. The during the build compose components with FAKE based on what components are needed for particular client.

Comment: I thought about the linking too. But as soon as I add a new file to the core project, it would need to be manually linked to all sub projects, right? AFAIK, there is no way to automate that

Comment: @filur, well, the link is simply a tag in the csproj file. Potentially you can create a tool or even extension to VS that will create/remove links automatically when file is created/removed.

Comment: I have created an extension that tracks files some time ago for different purpose https://bitbucket.org/andrii-litvinov/hgfiletracker. And I am sure you can find more examples. But still seems a little complex for the problem.

Comment: Well, since we're taling about ~50 project, adding a link manually for each new file is not an option for me :)

Comment: @filur, then automate if you decide to go this direction :). But as I mentioned in my answer I would go with well-defined components and configure those for each client. Can be done on either DI level in composition root for each client or during deployment as a CI configuration depending on the implementation.

Comment: IoC might be able to solve classes, but not physical files like views, script files etc

Comment: @filur physical files can be resolved by either custom build with conditional files, CAKE/FAKE or on CI with custom build steps.

Comment: "custom build with conditional files" and CAKE/FAKE would be pretty similar, right? As far as I can tell, powershell in a build can accomplish pretty much the same thing

Comment: @filur, by conditional files, I meant to provide a constant during the build to include certain files so no additional scripting needed. But that would be quite manual process to add/configure those files in csproj. I think same can be done with powershell, like run custom post-build script. Sure.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is super-admin section, where you could [de]activate different portions of the site, depending on customer.

Comment: Feature toggle would be a maintenance hell as the amount of customers grows I'm afraid

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: @filur but that is a correct approach. All the Features x Customers is just a 2 dimensional matrix of checkboxes. It is an approach you would take while building ERPs or CMSes. Exactly right tool for your case.

Answer (score 2):

There are some really good code answers here but if you're wanting an Automated Build system for every client and you have loads they could be a pain too setup.
When you could set up a script for Powershell that can do this

**pseudo code**

```
For each client site
    download base code to code/
    download this client's changes to code/ overwriting files
    msbuild ....
    copy client/ bin to build/client/
    Delete code/
End For each
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question requires some innovation. So look at my solution please:

Set up the core project structure for the classes that cover ***Model*** and ***Controller*** files and then use them with technique named [Add Existing Item As a Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx) which can share the followings:

- App logic common to both apps, but not portable
- User controls with no platform dependencies

Unfortunately that is not supported for razor ***views***. So the easiest thing to copy shared views is to have multiple layout files like famous *_Layout.cshtml* file, one in each web app. You can also [Compile your asp.net mvc Razor views into a separate dll](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) to use them like a Reference (as shared views).

For the ***Assets***, You can host all your style sheets (and some javascript if appropriate) from your main web application and access it from each web app.

The ***bin*** folder has core MVC dll files plus those that you add for using in your project and a `projectName.dll` file which will be created after building. You can simply Add/remove them by right clicking on References using *Add Reference* tool.